# Insert data if does not exist in MySQL database,

Tags: javascript, mysql

So, i've been running a .js app that stores & updates a database on both of a game and a discord bot. I've been using so far this following sql query to add/update data, but i've been looking for a way to only update if ${user.id} does not exist in the databse.

```
 INSERT INTO usermine
        (userID, mineCOOLDOWN, coal_mine, silver_mine, gold_mine, diamond_mine)
        VALUES( ${user.id}, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE userID = ${user.id};
```

I've seen a few other examples in here, but i was not succeful to implement it properly in my project (errored out or did not worked at all)

So more exactly what i need to do is:

> check if the ${user.id} is already in the database.
> If so don't insert anything.
>
> If the ${user.id} is not in the database, it should insert it's {user.id} and have all the other variables set to 1.

Comment: If you've already tried various things, please link to answers you've tried and mention the exact errors/results you got.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **INSERT IGNORE** feature of MySQL as:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO usermine
        (userID, mineCOOLDOWN, coal_mine, silver_mine, gold_mine, diamond_mine)
        VALUES( ${user.id}, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Would this only insert if the values are not in the table right?
As the ${user.id} would be unique and all the other data will change overtime from 1 to various values.

Comment: @ZetaReactor In that case you should have a look into it: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

> So, i've been running a .js app that stores & updates a database on
>   both of a game and a discord bot. I've been using so far this
>   following sql query to add/update data, but i've been looking for a
>   way to only update if ${user.id} does not exist in the databse.

You mean does not exist in table?

I think what you need is to create the table setting the id column as unique. Thus, trying to insert with the same id will simply fail.

e.g.

CREATE TABLE Persons (
    userID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    mineCOOLDOWN int NOT NULL,
    coal_mine int,
    silver_mine int,
    gold_mine int,
    diamond_mine int 
);

Comment: More exactly if the specific value - ${user.id} that would be a number does not exist in the table.

Each id is unique for each user.

As much as i've noticed the current setup sets up everything back to 1 if it's called again ( for example an user has 33 coal_mine and 1 of everything else. On the next call of the query it updates everything back to 1)